# How accurate is a Jest coverage test report? How is Jest test coverage calculated? How should I analyze the coverage findings?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I am working on updating tests for an Express microservice. For some directories (i.e. our `/utils` folder), I have written plenty of tests, which show 80-90% coverage. In the `/routes` directory, there are 0 tests, but it shows 100%.

Overall, I have this from our test coverage report:

`---------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files |    58.35 |    42.25 |    37.93 |    61.51 |
.
src/routes|      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
.
src/utils |    91.62 |    69.74 |     87.5 |    91.52 |                |`

I would analyze this as approximately 60% test coverage, but there wasn't much documentation on coverage.

Answer (score 3):

Any code executed during a test run, which could be your routes, depending on your tests, will be counted as covered.  Therefore, you might see large coverage but not have tests, since the route data was loaded and a test caused some evaluation to happen.  A useful tool on top of code coverage, is Mutation Testing which helps to analyze the quality of your tests.  I use [Stryker](https://stryker-mutator.io/) with Jest for Typescript projects.